# .htaccess not working on live site but working on localhost?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I am using ExpressionEngine and want to remove `index.php` from my URL's. I have this .htaccess file saved in the root folder. It works perfectly on localhost but when I upload it to the server it doesn't work. The correct URL appears in the address bar but the page stays on homepage. Any tips?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable Rewrite Engine
    # ------------------------------
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Redirect index.php Requests
    # ------------------------------
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]
    # Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
    # ------------------------------
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your [AllowOverride Directive in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is configured to allow `.htaccess` files and your server has `mod_rewrite` installed and active.

On Mac OS X, you'll find this file at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Look for the `<Directory>` Directive and change it to be:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
</Directory>
```

You'll need to restart Apache so it can read the new configuration:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

If you'd prefer to use a GUI to restart Apache, go to **Apple > System Preferences > Sharing** and toggle the checkbox next to the **Web Sharing** service.

If you're using Windows or any flavor of Linux, the same approach applies, but the Apache configuration may be in a different place, especially if you're using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/).

---

Also, for reference, the "officially supported method" by EllisLab for [Removing index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html) is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
    # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
</IfModule>
```