# htaccess redirect not working in live site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I did refer to:

[.htaccess not working on live site but working on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847625/htaccess-not-working-on-live-site-but-working-on-localhost)

[htaccess Custom Redirects not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710794/htaccess-custom-redirects-not-working)

and many more...but still not find a solution. It works fine on localhost but not in live server.

My live server is on **ubuntu.**

mod_rewrite.so is enabled and AllowOverride None is changed to **AllowOverride  ALl** in httpd.conf file.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

the above command when run via ssh, says **Module rewrite already enabled**.
I did restart the apache after making those changes.

When I checked **phpinfo**, however it's different from my localhost phpinfo. The live site not showing apache2handler nor loaded modules.

I've done few testing, it seems like the .htaccess file is not at all called. It's placed inside a sub directory of root folder.

> All I'm trying is to redirect any request to the subdirectory's
>   index.php file.

**This is my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do all `.htaccess` files not working on your live server or it is just this one ?

Comment: You can place some incorect syntax inside htaccess and check whether its calling htacess or not. If not then u have prob with configuration or url.

Comment: What's the path of the `httpd.conf` that you edited?

Comment: Always add `Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks` when working with rewrite rules. If it still doesn't work, Do what Jasmin said.

Comment: @lufc /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf

Comment: @Capsule, I did try that too

Comment: @JasminMistry, ya it doesnt affect when wrong syntax placed or even when the file is removed. This is actually an aws instance which just uses ip no domain yet , runs on http. It redirects to the instance from where this is copied(runs on https).

Comment: Check what `AccessFileName` is set to.

Comment: Did you use `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache` to restart apache?